# How to run an application a system / root in android

Tags: android, security, permissions, system, root

I've been searching about this topic but I haven't found a clear solution yet. As far as I know, you can specify different **protectionLevel** in your **AndroidManifest.xml**, those permissions allow other applications to interact with the one you are developing. As an example, imagine that I want to kill a processes, that is not mine (from another package) or that I want to install a driver I've developed. In both cases the problem is the same, those things need to be run as a system / root. How can I develop programs that require system / root permissions, do I need an special license?

**Note:** Please, note that granting the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

Using `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` does not work either.

Also, consider that I cannot ask the users to have their mobiles "rooted".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to ask users to have their devices rooted, but get root access in your App? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: I want to have root / system permission without having them to use exploits / hacks to get their devices rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 Process myprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

to request root access.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, as far as I know this only works if the mobile is rooted. I've just tried it again, and it does not work.

Comment: Yes if you want to run your process in root level you need the device to have root access.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
Either you ask your users to root their devices or you limit your applications abilities to the things you can do without root access.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me, I was wondering if there was an special license or a special way to sign the application.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to not displaying the GUI of requesting root authorization from the user? in a rooted device, installed as a system application under /system/app